# Using a String List as history

Tags: c#

Such a simple issue, but I don't have a clue how to fix this.
I have a ListView with Strings in a c# Winform App.
By clicking on a item I will add the item text to a string list.
(Directory names should go in a history list)

The problem is:
The string list should be accessible from other methods.

I tried this:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var HistList = new List<string>();
    }
```

I can not access the HistList from anywhere, I've tried this:

```
    private void listView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var firstSelectedItem = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
        HistList.add(firstSelectedItem.Text); 
    }
```

The HistList is not visible in the Listview event or anywhere else.
Maybe I should make a Class for this e.g.:

```
    class HistList
    {
        private static HistList _History = new HistList();
        public static HistList HistL
        {
            get { return _History; }
        }
        private List<string> HistoryL = new List<string>();
        private HistList()
        {
            // Initialize here
        }
    }
```

But this is cumbersome. I want to add and read and delete items in the list from several places.

So, no idea how to proceed

Comment: Scope of variable is wrong (it's local ONLY to the constructor); move it outside of the constructor. So `public List<string> HistList { get; set; } = new List<string>(); public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
    }` (based on first image above)

Comment: You just need to move your variable to the class-level and make it a field.

Comment: @Steve: To clarify your statement: *scope* is defined as the region of *source code text* in which the *name* of a thing may be used *without qualification*. Scope is about source code. *Lifetime* by contrast is the *interval of time in the execution of the program* in which a variable's storage exists. Lifetime is about *storage management of a running program*. It is very easy to confuse scope with lifetime, and they are related, but when teaching novices it is a good idea to avoid conflating these two related concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically, a variable is in-scope anywhere between the curly brackets in which it is declared and child curly brackets

```
class A{

    int X;

    void Method1{ 

        int y;

        if(...){
            int z;
        }  

        for(...){

        }
    }
  
    void Method2(){

    }
}
```

- X is usable anywhere in this class - Method1 or 2, the `if`, the `for`; everywhere
- y is usable anywhere below its declaration in Method1, including the `if` and `for` - can't insert new lines above `int y` that reference y, nor can you use it in Method2
- z is usable anywhere below its declaration inside the `if` only - not the body of method 1, not the for loop either

PublicThings like X are named in PascalCase

localThings like y, z are named in camelCase

Comment: So I need to proceed this "HistList" Class, with a method to add or get items. A direct access of the List is not possible.

Comment: Erm, you need to make the list like X

Comment: Sorry, I am not that experienced but I really stuck here. Theoretical it is fine, but practically - not at all. Here what I tried:

Answer (score 0):

No Idea wheather it finally fits my needs, however this is what I did:

...

```
class HistoList
        {
            private List<string> HistoryL = new List<string>();// = new List<string>(); //why is it allways null??

            public HistoList() { }//Constructor

            
            public void AddToHist(string PutIn) 
            {
                HistoryL.Add(PutIn);
            }
            public string TakeFromHist
            {
                get
                {
                    if (HistoryL.Count > 0)
                    {
                        HistoryL.RemoveAt(HistoryL.Count-1);//remove last
                        return HistoryL[HistoryL.Count-1];//return remaining last
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        return HistoryL[^1];//return last
                    };
                }
            }   
            
        }
```

...

I used it in a console app so far:

...

```
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            HistoList Hi = new HistoList();
           
            Hi.AddToHist("This");
            Hi.AddToHist("is");
            Hi.AddToHist("Shit");

            Console.WriteLine(Hi.TakeFromHist + "<= this should be -is-");
            
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

...

Improvements welcome

Comment: Please not not add an answer to your question, with a new question...   Also we need to read very carefully what you wrote here to find out that you are actually trying to ask another question.... (because an answer is expected on this place...)